# Can we see the past view of our galaxy while observing in the sky because of the homogeneous structure of our universe?

Tags: cosmology, universe, big-bang

As a sense, we think that simple speed addition should work ($V_1+V_2$) for all references but  we know today that universe does not match our this sense. We cannot exceed the speed of light in any references.

This example shows that we can fail if we use our senses to explain some  concepts in universe.  We feel a line should go endless without a loop to itself but every definition of big bang mentions that the whole universe is homogeneous and there is no big bang center.
If so, I have some questions about our universe geometry:

1. Can a line go to endless in the universe as we imagine if the distribution of matters in the universe is homogeneous after bing-bang ?
2. Is there any border of observed universe if universe is expanding?
3. If the universe is homogeneous and it is expanding as similar as  a balloon surface like sphere, can we see the past view of our galaxy while observing in the sky?

I will appreciate if someone explains more detail how the universe geometry structure is if we have a homogeneous universe after big bang.

Thanks for answers

Comment: *"I will appreciate if someone explains more detail how the universe geometry structure is"*  I think many people (including cosmologists) would share this desire!  :)

Comment: The universe appears homogenous at the largest scales, but is probably finitely old and infinitely large. Also, due to the accelerating expansion of space, as time goes on we'll see less and less of the universe, not more. So we'll probably never see the past of a copy of the Milky Way.

Comment: We don't know what the large scale structure of the universe is. It's not even clear that it is observable.